# jQuery crossfade with background images

Tags: jquery, plugins, background, fade

I have a jquery crossfade working but the only problem is it fades between two physical images that it places and I need it to fade between background images instead.

If there is already a good script that does this that'd be great or maybe what I have can be easily altered.

Here is the plugin code:

```
    /*
 * Copyright 2007-2009 by Tobia Conforto <tobia.conforto@gmail.com>
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General
 * Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your
 * option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
 * implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License
 * for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program; if not, write to
 * the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
 *
 * Versions: 0.1    2007-08-19  Initial release
 *                  2008-08-21  Re-released under GPL v2
 *           0.1.1  2008-09-18  Compatibility with prototype.js
 *           0.2    2008-10-15  Linkable images, contributed by Tim Rainey <tim@zmlabs.com>
 *           0.3    2008-10-22  Added option to repeat the animation a number of times, then stop
 *           0.3.1  2008-11-11  Better error messages
 *           0.3.2  2008-11-11  Fixed a couple of CSS bugs, contributed by Erwin Bot <info@ixgcms.nl>
 *           0.3.3  2008-12-14  Added onclick option
 *           0.3.4  2009-03-12  Added shuffle option, contributed by Ralf Santbergen <ralf_santbergen@hotmail.com>
 *           0.3.5  2009-03-12  Fixed usage of href parameter in 'Ken Burns' mode
 *           0.3.6  2009-04-16  Added alt option
 *           0.3.7  2009-05-14  Fixed bug when container div doesn't have a position CSS attribute
 */

jQuery.fn.crossSlide = function(opts, plan) {
 var self = this,
   self_width = this.width(),
   self_height = this.height();

 // generic utilities
 function format(str) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
   str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\{' + (i-1) + '}', 'g'), arguments[i]);
  return str;
 }

 function abort() {
  arguments[0] = 'crossSlide: ' + arguments[0];
  throw format.apply(null, arguments);
 }

 // first preload all the images, while getting their actual width and height
 (function(proceed) {

  var n_loaded = 0;
  function loop(i, img) {
   // for (i = 0; i < plan.length; i++) but with independent var i, img (for the closures)
   img.onload = function(e) {
    n_loaded++;
    plan[i].width = img.width;
    plan[i].height = img.height;
    if (n_loaded == plan.length)
     proceed();
   }
   img.src = plan[i].src;
   if (i + 1 < plan.length)
    loop(i + 1, new Image());
  }
  loop(0, new Image());

 })(function() {  // then proceed

  // utility to parse "from" and "to" parameters
  function parse_position_param(param) {
   var zoom = 1;
   var tokens = param.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '').split(/\s+/);
   if (tokens.length > 3) throw new Error();
   if (tokens[0] == 'center')
    if (tokens.length == 1)
     tokens = ['center', 'center'];
    else if (tokens.length == 2 && tokens[1].match(/^[\d.]+x$/i))
     tokens = ['center', 'center', tokens[1]];
   if (tokens.length == 3)
    zoom = parseFloat(tokens[2].match(/^([\d.]+)x$/i)[1]);
   var pos = tokens[0] + ' ' + tokens[1];
   if (pos == 'left top'      || pos == 'top left')      return { xrel:  0, yrel:  0, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'left center'   || pos == 'center left')   return { xrel:  0, yrel: .5, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'left bottom'   || pos == 'bottom left')   return { xrel:  0, yrel:  1, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'center top'    || pos == 'top center')    return { xrel: .5, yrel:  0, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'center center')                           return { xrel: .5, yrel: .5, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'center bottom' || pos == 'bottom center') return { xrel: .5, yrel:  1, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'right top'     || pos == 'top right')     return { xrel:  1, yrel:  0, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'right center'  || pos == 'center right')  return { xrel:  1, yrel: .5, zoom: zoom };
   if (pos == 'right bottom'  || pos == 'bottom right')  return { xrel:  1, yrel:  1, zoom: zoom };
   return {
    xrel: parseInt(tokens[0].match(/^(\d+)%$/)[1]) / 100,
    yrel: parseInt(tokens[1].match(/^(\d+)%$/)[1]) / 100,
    zoom: zoom
   };
  }

  // utility to compute the css for a given phase between p.from and p.to
  // phase = 1: begin fade-in,  2: end fade-in,  3: begin fade-out,  4: end fade-out
  function position_to_css(p, phase) {
   switch (phase) {
    case 1:
     var pos = 0;
     break;
    case 2:
     var pos = fade_ms / (p.time_ms + 2 * fade_ms);
     break;
    case 3:
     var pos = 1 - fade_ms / (p.time_ms + 2 * fade_ms);
     break;
    case 4:
     var pos = 1;
     break;
   }
   return {
    left:   Math.round(p.from.left   + pos * (p.to.left   - p.from.left  )),
    top:    Math.round(p.from.top    + pos * (p.to.top    - p.from.top   )),
    width:  Math.round(p.from.width  + pos * (p.to.width  - p.from.width )),
    height: Math.round(p.from.height + pos * (p.to.height - p.from.height))
   };
  }

  // check global params
  if (! opts.fade)
   abort('missing fade parameter.');
  if (opts.speed && opts.sleep)
   abort('you cannot set both speed and sleep at the same time.');
  // conversion from sec to ms; from px/sec to px/ms
  var fade_ms = Math.round(opts.fade * 1000);
  if (opts.sleep)
   var sleep = Math.round(opts.sleep * 1000);
  if (opts.speed)
   var speed = opts.speed / 1000,
     fade_px = Math.round(fade_ms * speed);

  // set container css
  self.empty().css({
   overflow: 'hidden',
   padding: 0
  });
  if (! /^(absolute|relative|fixed)$/.test(self.css('position')))
   self.css({ position: 'relative' });
  if (! self.width() || ! self.height())
   abort('container element does not have its own width and height');

  // random sorting
  if (opts.shuffle)
   plan.sort(function() {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
   });

  // prepare each image
  for (var i = 0; i < plan.length; ++i) {

   var p = plan[i];
   if (! p.src)
    abort('missing src parameter in picture {0}.', i + 1);

   if (speed) { // speed/dir mode

    // check parameters and translate speed/dir mode into full mode (from/to/time)
    switch (p.dir) {
     case 'up':
      p.from = { xrel: .5, yrel: 0, zoom: 1 };
      p.to   = { xrel: .5, yrel: 1, zoom: 1 };
      var slide_px = p.height - self_height - 2 * fade_px;
      break;
     case 'down':
      p.from = { xrel: .5, yrel: 1, zoom: 1 };
      p.to   = { xrel: .5, yrel: 0, zoom: 1 };
      var slide_px = p.height - self_height - 2 * fade_px;
      break;
     case 'left':
      p.from = { xrel: 0, yrel: .5, zoom: 1 };
      p.to   = { xrel: 1, yrel: .5, zoom: 1 };
      var slide_px = p.width - self_width - 2 * fade_px;
      break;
     case 'right':
      p.from = { xrel: 1, yrel: .5, zoom: 1 };
      p.to   = { xrel: 0, yrel: .5, zoom: 1 };
      var slide_px = p.width - self_width - 2 * fade_px;
      break;
     default:
      abort('missing or malformed "dir" parameter in picture {0}.', i + 1);
    }
    if (slide_px <= 0)
     abort('picture number {0} is too short for the desired fade duration.', i + 1);
    p.time_ms = Math.round(slide_px / speed);

   } else if (! sleep) { // full mode

    // check and parse parameters
    if (! p.from || ! p.to || ! p.time)
     abort('missing either speed/sleep option, or from/to/time params in picture {0}.', i + 1);
    try {
     p.from = parse_position_param(p.from)
    } catch (e) {
     abort('malformed "from" parameter in picture {0}.', i + 1);
    }
    try {
     p.to = parse_position_param(p.to)
    } catch (e) {
     abort('malformed "to" parameter in picture {0}.', i + 1);
    }
    if (! p.time)
     abort('missing "time" parameter in picture {0}.', i + 1);
    p.time_ms = Math.round(p.time * 1000)
   }

   // precalculate left/top/width/height bounding values
   if (p.from)
    jQuery.each([ p.from, p.to ], function(i, from_to) {
     from_to.width  = Math.round(p.width  * from_to.zoom);
     from_to.height = Math.round(p.height * from_to.zoom);
     from_to.left   = Math.round((self_width  - from_to.width)  * from_to.xrel);
     from_to.top    = Math.round((self_height - from_to.height) * from_to.yrel);
    });

   // append the image (or anchor) element to the container
   var elm;
   if (p.href)
    elm = jQuery(format('<a href="{0}"><img src="{1}"/></a>', p.href, p.src));
   else
    elm = jQuery(format('<img src="{0}"/>', p.src));
   if (p.onclick)
    elm.click(p.onclick);
   if (p.alt)
    elm.find('img').attr('alt', p.alt);
   elm.appendTo(self);
  }
  speed = undefined;  // speed mode has now been translated to full mode

  // find images to animate and set initial css attributes
  var imgs = self.find('img').css({
   position: 'absolute',
   visibility: 'hidden',
   top: 0,
   left: 0,
   border: 0
  });

  // show first image
  imgs.eq(0).css({ visibility: 'visible' });
  if (! sleep)
   imgs.eq(0).css(position_to_css(plan[0], 2));

  // create animation chain
  var countdown = opts.loop;
  function create_chain(i, chainf) {
   // building the chain backwards, or inside out

   if (i % 2 == 0) {
    if (sleep) {

     // still image sleep

     var i_sleep = i / 2,
       i_hide = (i_sleep - 1 + plan.length) % plan.length,
       img_sleep = imgs.eq(i_sleep),
       img_hide = imgs.eq(i_hide);

     var newf = function() {
      img_hide.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      setTimeout(chainf, sleep);
     };

    } else {

     // single image slide

     var i_slide = i / 2,
       i_hide = (i_slide - 1 + plan.length) % plan.length,
       img_slide = imgs.eq(i_slide),
       img_hide = imgs.eq(i_hide),
       time = plan[i_slide].time_ms,
       slide_anim = position_to_css(plan[i_slide], 3);

     var newf = function() {
      img_hide.css('visibility', 'hidden');
      img_slide.animate(slide_anim, time, 'linear', chainf);
     };

    }
   } else {
    if (sleep) {

     // still image cross-fade

     var i_from = Math.floor(i / 2),
       i_to = Math.ceil(i / 2) % plan.length,
       img_from = imgs.eq(i_from),
       img_to = imgs.eq(i_to),
       from_anim = {},
       to_init = { visibility: 'visible' },
       to_anim = {};

     if (i_to > i_from) {
      to_init.opacity = 0;
      to_anim.opacity = 1;
     } else {
      from_anim.opacity = 0;
     }

     var newf = function() {
      img_to.css(to_init);
      if (from_anim.opacity != undefined)
       img_from.animate(from_anim, fade_ms, 'linear', chainf);
      else
       img_to.animate(to_anim, fade_ms, 'linear', chainf);
     };

    } else {

     // cross-slide + cross-fade

     var i_from = Math.floor(i / 2),
       i_to = Math.ceil(i / 2) % plan.length,
       img_from = imgs.eq(i_from),
       img_to = imgs.eq(i_to),
       from_anim = position_to_css(plan[i_from], 4),
       to_init = position_to_css(plan[i_to], 1),
       to_anim = position_to_css(plan[i_to], 2);

     if (i_to > i_from) {
      to_init.opacity = 0;
      to_anim.opacity = 1;
     } else {
      from_anim.opacity = 0;
     }
     to_init.visibility = 'visible';

     var newf = function() {
      img_from.animate(from_anim, fade_ms, 'linear');
      img_to.css(to_init);
      img_to.animate(to_anim, fade_ms, 'linear', chainf);
     };

    }
   }

   // if the loop option was requested, push a countdown check
   if (opts.loop && i == plan.length * 2 - 2) {
    var newf_orig = newf;
    newf = function() {
     if (--countdown) newf_orig();
    }
   }

   if (i > 0)
    return create_chain(i - 1, newf);
   else
    return newf;
  }
  var animation = create_chain(plan.length * 2 - 1, function() { return animation(); });

  // start animation
  animation();

 });

 return self;
};
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
<div id="foreground">

<style type="text/css">
  #slides2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#slides2').crossSlide({
      sleep: 2,
      fade: 1
    }, [
      { src: 'http://treethink.treethink.net/images/foreground.png' },
      { src: 'http://treethink.treethink.net/images/foreground-night.png' },
    ]);
  });

</script>

<div id="slides2"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code above I presume you are trying to make the images fade/appear in the #foreground, instead of the div #slides2.

Try replacing the id of the element calling the crossSlide method, like this:

```
$('#foreground').crossSlide({
      sleep: 2,
      fade: 1
    }, [
      { src: 'http://treethink.treethink.net/images/foreground.png' },
      { src: 'http://treethink.treethink.net/images/foreground-night.png' },
    ]);
```

And maybe also the CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  #foregroundslides2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
  }
</style>
```